# how not to match pattern inside parenthesis in preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to get the src of all the image tag from a web page. But I'm confused as to how not to match the patterns inside the parenthesis. In this case `gif|jpg|png|jpeg`

```
$img_src_pattern = '/src="?.+\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg)"/';
preg_match_all($img_src_pattern, $contents, $img_matches);
```

So when printing out `$img_matches` I get an array like this:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
    [0] => src="http://s9.addthis.com/button1-bm.gif" 
    [1] => src="http://s9.addthis.com/button1-bm.gif" ) 
  [1] => Array ( [0] => gif [1] => gif ) 
)
```

And here's what I want to get:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
    [0] => src="http://s9.addthis.com/button1-bm.gif" 
    [1] => src="http://s9.addthis.com/button1-bm.gif" ) 
)
```

This is really the part of `preg_match` that confuses me. Can you enlighten me on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just ignore it, since it belongs to another index in the array.

Or you can change the capturing group `(pattern)` to non-capturing group `(?:pattern)`:

```
'/src="?.+\.(?:gif|jpg|png|jpeg)"/'
```

Your current regex, apart from finding a match to the whole regex, also "captures" (i.e. remembers) the text matched by the regex `gif|jpg|png|jpeg`, due to the effect of capturing group `()` surrounding it. Non-capturing group will retain the *grouping* property, but will not capture the text matched by the sub-expression `gif|jpg|png|jpeg`.

`preg_match_all` output a 2 dimensional array, where the first dimension is the capturing group (index 0 will contain the text matched by the whole regex), and the second dimension is the id of the matches that it has found.